# How can I retrieve images from Gallery in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an image picker in Flutter where I can select image from gallery.

I don't know about some built-in code or library for an image picker.

Comment: Use [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package?

Comment: Use  https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager  package

Answer (score 5):

I know I might be a little bit late but you can use this library.

It returns the gallery and the images of a gallery it's currently under development, but should work on Android perfectly, whereas for iOS it's not fully implemented yet.

#### How to use it

To get albums:

```
List<PhoneAlbum> phoneAlbums = [];
final customImagePicker = CustomImagePicker();


Future<void> getGallery() async {
    try {
      await customImagePicker.getAlbums(callback: (msg) {
        setState(() {
          phoneAlbums = msg;
        });
      });
    } on PlatformException {}
  }
```

The phone album has these properties

```
String id;
String name;
String coverUri;
int photosCount;
```

To get photos of an album:

```
 List<PhonePhoto> images = [];

 final customImagePicker = CustomImagePicker();

Future<void> getPhotosOfGallery(String albumID) async {
    List<PhonePhoto> allImages = [];
    try {
      final cancelElement = await customImagePicker.getPhotosOfAlbum(albumID, callback: (msg) {
        print('The message is $msg');
      });
    } on PlatformException {}

    setState(() {
      images = allImages;
    });
  }
```

The phone photo has these properties:

```
 String id;
 String albumName;
 String photoUri;
```

This helps you to display the images in the way you prefer, and very soon fetching video will be available, as well as pagination (Lazy loading) in order to improve the performance

https://pub.dev/packages/custom_image_picker

Comment: Great effort, I wish it was documented

Comment: @MikhailBaynov thanks for your comment, it's actually documented in the GitHub repository's README.md.

https://github.com/TahaMalas/custom_image_picker

I am currently uploading a new version to the pub.dev

Comment: The plugin `custom_image_picker` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.