# Flutter - How to choose images programmatically (without user interaction)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to programmatically choose images based on meta data like date and location.
The whole procedure should take place locally on the mobile (iOS & Android).
There shouldn't be any user interaction. image_picker is not the solution.
Idea is to pick am image of a day by chance (eventually also based on location) to automatically add it to a diary.

Haven't found any package or answer. Hope I didn't miss anything.
Can I perhaps call the Image app with a context?
Can I write a package myself to complete this?
Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this package [custom_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_image_picker), [GitHub repo](https://github.com/TahaMalas/custom_image_picker).

More details at [How can I retrieve images from Gallery in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663096/how-can-i-retrieve-images-from-gallery-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Looks like what I was searching for assuming the pics come with their meta data. I’ll give it a try and get back here. Tried to upvote your answer but my reputation is too low 

Comment: Unfortunately the package does not work as expected. An empty iOS emulator with two more albums will only show "Recent" as the only album, which is wrong as I added two more albums. On a real phone with my personal id (around 20k pictures) the package throws an exception. The comments on git hub issues also rather reflect a dead package. I'll experiment some more with the Recent album I get. And post an issue on git hub regarding the exception I got. If anyone knows any other options I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

To display an image from your internal memory you can do so like this:

`Image.file(yourImageFileLocation)`